# PL/SQL - different value

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
SELECT sum((DECODE(transaction_code,'INV',quantity,( (-1)* quantity)))) total
        FROM INVENTORY_TRANSACTION_HIST_TAB
       WHERE order_no = 9999;
```

returns: `1160721`

in pl/sql block

```
declare
   cursor c is      
      SELECT sum((DECODE(transaction_code,'INV',quantity,( (-1)* quantity)))) total
        FROM INVENTORY_TRANSACTION_HIST_TAB
       WHERE order_no = 9999                                
begin
  for rec_ in c loop
     dbms_output.put_line(rec_.total_consumed);
  end loop;
end;
```

returns: `1160720,999999999999995`

Any ideas? How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You will get the same result when you do this one in SQLplus:

```
SET NUMWIDTH 50;

SELECT sum((DECODE(transaction_code,'INV',quantity,( (-1)* quantity)))) total
        FROM INVENTORY_TRANSACTION_HIST_TAB
       WHERE order_no = 9999;
```

The reason is on SQLplus the **default** nubmer format is `SET NUMWIDTH 10`, so result is rounded to 10 digits by default.

In your PL/SQL block you do not round anything. Some time ago I had the same issue and I got answer from [Tom Kyte](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:7080171800346634518).

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want this rounded to an appropriate value.

Perhaps the simplest way is to cast this to a decimal:

```
SELECT cast(sum((DECODE(transaction_code,'INV',quantity,( (-1)* quantity)))) as decimal(15, 2) as total
FROM INVENTORY_TRANSACTION_HIST_TAB
WHERE order_no = 9999;
```